# Find the maximum value of $y$ with differentiation

Tags: derivatives

I have the following problem to solve but I don't know where to start.

The sum of two positive numbers is $50$. One number is $x$ so the other number must be
$50 − x$. Let the product be $y$. Use differentiation to find the maximum value of $y$.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

$x\cdot(50-x)=y$ so differentiating with respect to $x$ we get $50-2x=0$ so $x=25$. Now we differentiate again and we get $-2$ which is less than $0$. We have  $f'(0)<0$ so at $25$ there exists a maximum. Thus substituting $x=25$ into the original equation gives us the  maximum value as $625$.

Answer (score 0):

with AM-GM we have $$\sqrt{x(50-x)}\le \frac{x+50-x}{2}=25$$ the equal sign holds if $$x=50-x$$ this means $x=25$

Comment: Great method... But I think he specified that it should be done using integration.